# React Query: Cache Invalidation Issue with Pagination and Filtering in useQuery

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm facing a cache invalidation issue in React Query when implementing both pagination and filtering in a table. Below is the code snippet for context:

```
const { isLoading, data: tableData } = useQuery({
    queryKey: [`transactions`, filters, pagination],
    queryFn: async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}transaction?${new URLSearchParams(pagination).toString()}&${new URLSearchParams(filters).toString()}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
            },
        });

        const transformedData = response.data.data.transactions.map(
            (transaction) => ({
                // ... (your data transformation logic)
            })
        );

        return transformedData;
    },
    
});
```

The challenge arises when I change both pagination and filtering options. If the new pagination option is not in the React Query cache, the table updates correctly. However, if the pagination option is already in the cache, the table doesn't reflect the changes due to the previous filtering.

How can I ensure that changes in both pagination and filtering options properly invalidate the cache and fetch the updated data from the server using React Query? Are there specific configurations or practices I should consider in my implementation?

I appreciate any insights or recommendations to overcome this cache invalidation issue. Thank you!

Comment: Do you really want to "invalidate the cache" every time the user changes the pagination or filtering? If you really want data to be refetched every single time user changes pagination/filter, the simplest approach is to set `staleTime` to `0`.

Comment: the question is: what is your `staleTime` set to? With the default of `0`, you should see cached data for any input  + a background refetch. Of course, if that time is higher, you will just read data from the cache.